# Display CFOUTPUT Group - Grouping Numbers - Most First

Tags: sql, ms-access, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to run a report on incidents.  This code works fine to display it.  But I'd like to get the report displaying the most incidents first descending.  Adding an order by does not do it.  I am also counting the amount of incidents by doing a group count.  And thus able to get the percentage.  But the display is displaying the incident code in order - but not the actual amount of incidents in order.  I'm at bit of loss - can't seem to find solution on Goog or here...  Using CF9 and Access...

Displays like this...

Call Type Call Numbers

Dollar Loss Fire 2
Medical CoResponse 11
Vehicle Accident 6
Rubbish or Grass Fire 1
Gas Leak - Natural Gas 5
Alarm - No Fire - Catalogue Alarm 1
Alarm - No Fire - CO Alarm 4
Complaint Investigation 2

I'd like it to display the most first and then decrease like this...

Medical CoResponse 11 
Vehicle Accident 6
Gas Leak - Natural Gas 5
Alarm - No Fire - CO Alarm 4
Dollar Loss Fire 2
Complaint Investigation 2
Rubbish or Grass Fire 1
Alarm - No Fire - Catalogue Alarm 1

```
    <cfquery name="calls" datasource="report">
select * from master
where eventdate like '%#yydate#%'
order by incidentcode
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>
<b>#yydate# #calls.recordcount# Calls</b><br><br>
</cfoutput>

<table cellpadding=8 cellspacing=0 border=1>
<tr bgcolor=b3b3b3>
<td align=center>Call Type</td>
<td align=center>Call Numbers</td>
<td align=center>Percent</td>
</tr>

  <cfoutput query=calls group="incidentcode">
  <cfset groupCount = 0>
  <cfoutput>
  <cfset groupCount = groupCount + 1>
  </cfoutput>
  <cfquery name="code" datasource="report">
  select * from incidentcode
  where id = #incidentcode#
  </cfquery>
<tr>
<td align=center>#code.event#</td>
<td align=center>#groupcount#</td>
<td align=center>
<cfset perc = (#groupcount# / #calls.recordcount#) * 100>
#numberformat(Perc, "_._")# %
</td>
</tr>  
  </cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't complete, but hopefully gets you on the right track. You should be able to write your queries as one query and then output it that way using aggregate totals.

```
<cfquery name="calls">
SELECT m.incidentcode ic, ic.event event, SUM(m.incdentcode) total
FROM master m
  INNER JOIN incidentcode ic ON m.incidentcode = ic.id
where eventdate like '%#yydate#%'
group by m.incidentcode, event
order by ic
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="calls">
  <tr>
    <td>#code.event#</td>
    <td>#code.total#</td>
  </tr>
</cfoutput>
```

The preferred way would be to create one query, but in keeping with your original syntax this should work as well. You may want to double check that sortedStruct is being sorted correctly. It might sort by key name first.

```
<cfset allCalls = {}>
<cfset totalCount = 0>
<cfoutput query=calls group="incidentcode">
  <cfset groupCount = 0>
  <cfoutput>
    <cfset groupCount++>
  </cfoutput>
  <cfset totalCount+=groupCount>
  <cfquery name="code" datasource="report">
  select * from incidentcode
  where id = <cfqueryparam cf_sql_type="cf_sql_varchar" value="#incidentcode#">
  </cfquery>
  <cfset allCalls[code.event] = groupcount>
</cfoutput>

<cfset sortedStruct = structSort(allCalls,'numeric','desc')><!--- returns an array ordered the way you want --->
<cfoutput>
  <cfloop array="#sortedStruct#" index="event">
    <tr>
      <td>#event#</td>
      <td>#allCalls[event]#</td>
      <td>#numberFormat(allCalls[event] / totalCount * 100,'00.00')#</td>
    </tr>
  </cfloop> 
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Sorry - will admit - a little lost with all that...Event is not in master... I am trying to decipher things...

Comment: The query is pulling rows from both master and incident code based on matching incidentcode.

Comment: Not working - code.event is in a different table than master.  Master table carries an identifying incident code number, which I am able to pull and count (just not able to display as desired), while the incident code table carries the descriptor of event. The code query is only pulling the text of what the incidentcode is - and should not need to be joined/unioned - as it is just displaying the text of the code.

Comment: I think you need to look up on how joins work. If event is in incidentcode (like your question says) then it will show in the query.

Comment: The code.event table has no associated count to it... There is no need to use it other than to get a later descriptor of what the incidentcode is... ie: incident Code 1 = VehicleAccident, Code 2 = Gas Leak - so in the master table - there are 6 - code (1) for Vehicle Accident and 5 code (2) for Gas Leak - so say 11 total records - 6 of one code type and 5 of another code type... I need to sort and list these by 6 then 5...  Event from descriptor can be ignored until it is needed... As it is just text associated to the codetype - and mucks everything up...

Comment: I still don't think you're understanding how joins work and are going through a lot of extra effort you shouldn't be, but nevertheless I've added an answer that keeps your original format of querying for each record in the master table.

Comment: Appears to have worked... I was thinking I might need to go to an array...  I'll clean stuff up and get ur answer sorted... Thx much